# Onscreen-Keyboard Layout for Gnome Terminal always shows up with the english layout

Tags: gnome-terminal, 23.04, onscreen-keyboard

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 with a Dell Precision 7390 2in1. That means I am partly working in kind-of tablet mode using the onscreen keyboard.
If I open a gnome terminal there the keyboard layout always switches to "QWERTY", even though the onscreen keyboard settings show that German is selected (which should have QWERTZ instead).

I already tried to install the english layout as well and switched between both, but also this doesn't help. In fact it does not even seem to have any effect as long as the input focus of the keyboard is on a gnome terminal (the on screen keyboard layout stays QWERTY not matter what layout I select).

Can somebody help me to change the keyboard layout of the on screen keyboard, so it fits the settings?
Is this a bug?

Btw. for other applications like when I open the on screen keyboard for firefox, it displays the QWERTZ layout as expected.

Comment: It's apparently something related to GNOME itself as I'm experiencing it also on Manjaro, GNOME 45.3. Maybe related: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/1167